# Match and parse the content of a square-braced placeholder in text

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-match, text-parsing

I have a PHP variable (`$content`) where I need to find a certain pattern that looks like this:

```
[gallery::name/of/the/folder/]
```

I would like to search:

```
- starting with literal characters `[gallery::`
- any other character (variable length)
- ending with "]"
```

So far, in PHP I have:

```
preg_match('/\[gallery\:/', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I can find `[gallery:` but that's it.

I would like to be able to find the rest (`:name/of/the/folder/]`).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try capturing it:

```
preg_match("/\[gallery::(.*?)]/", $content, $m);
```

Now `$m` is an array:

```
0 => [gallery::/name/of/the/folder/]
1 => /name/of/the/folder/
```

Comment: If the string is 'starting with' something, make sure to prepend a '^' character to "\\[gallery"

Comment: wouldn't multiple occurences ([gallery::/name/of/the/folder/][gallery::/name/of/the/folder/]) cause problems with using a greedy capture on all characters?

Comment: this will match `[gallery::]` i would change it to `[gallery::(.+?)]`

Comment: I think OP meant that the pattern started with `[gallery::`, rather than the search string itself... Maybe... Not sure.

Comment: @TimHoolihan it is a non-greedy capture

Comment: @nathanjosiah Using a `+` is a valid answer too, but since it was supposed to be "any length" I figured 0 was included - after all, what if the path were the empty string (in other words, the current directory)?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer guys. It almost works but I'm having problems with the "/" in the folder name. If I type [gallery::/name/of/the/folder/] it doesn't find any results. But if I take out the "/" I find what I'm looking for. Anyway of finding with the "/" or do I need to replace it with another character?

Comment: Are you sure you're typing the path in the right place? Might be a silly question, but there's no reason why a `/` in the search string would fail to match this regex.

Answer (score 2):

change your regex to

```
'/\[gallery::([A-Za-z\/]+)\]/'
```

Since I put the folder/path part in parenthesis, you should get a capture group out of it.