# Find exact string inside a string

Tags: php, string

I have two strings "Mures"  and "Maramures". How can I build a search function that when someone searches for Mures it will return him only the posts that contain the "Mures" word and not the one that contain the "Maramures" word. I tried strstr until now but it does now work.

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Are `Mures` and `mures` the same?

Comment: You will have to write code to create the search feature. http://php.net

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this with regex, and surrounding the word with `\b` word boundary

`preg_match("~\bMures\b~",$string)`

**example:**

```
$string = 'Maramures';
if ( preg_match("~\bMures\b~",$string) )
  echo "matched";
else
  echo "no match";
```

Comment: I'm stuck by seeing that you are use `~` instead `/`.  But I found: "Often used delimiters are forward slashes `/`, hash signs `#` and tildes `~`." All methods are valid for delimited patterns. I just need to use no sensitive parameter by adding `i` in the end: `preg_match("~\bMures\b~i",$string)`

Answer (score 6):

Use preg_match function

```
if (preg_match("/\bMures\b/i", $string)) {
    echo "OK.";
} else {
    echo "KO.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you check the result of strstr? Try this here:

```
$string = 'Maramures';
$search = 'Mures';
$contains = strstr(strtolower($string), strtolower($search)) !== false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a dumb solution and there's a better one. But you can add spaces to the source and destination strings at the start and finish of the strings and then search for " Mures ". Easy to implement and no need to use any other functions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do various things:

- search for ' Mures ' (spaces around)
- search case sensitive (so 'mures' will be found in 'Maramures' but 'Mures' won't)
- use a regular expression to search in the string ( 'word boundary + Mures + word boundary') -- have a look at this too: [Php find string with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142658/php-find-string-with-regex)

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsString($needle, $tag_array){
    foreach($tag_array as $tag){
        if(strpos($tag,$needle) !== False){
            echo $tag . " contains the string " . $needle . "<br />";
        } else {        
            echo $tag . " does not contain the string " . $needle;
        }

    }
}
$tag_array = ['Mures','Maramures'];
$needle    = 'Mures';
containsString($needle, $tag_array);
```

A function like this would work... Might not be as sexy as `preg_match` though.

Answer (score 0):

The very simple way should be similar to this.

```
    $stirng = 'Mures';

    if (preg_match("/$string/", $text)) {
        // Matched
    } else {
        // Not matched
    }
```