# Altering search string for full word searches

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a search string like this ...

```
shop.php?querytp=&query22=&query20=&query21=&querytp1=&querytp2=Shed&querytp3=
```

which does the job up to a point but I would like to stop the search from finding words within words so that a search for 'shed' doesn't pull up 'brushed' or 'polished' for instance.  If I add + to the URL manually so that it becomes ...

```
shop.php?querytp=&query22=&query20=&query21=&querytp1=&querytp2=+Shed&querytp3=
```

that does the trick.  Lots of the queries are empty at times.

Can htaccess sort this out for me?  Bit beyond me this to be honest with you.

Thanks

Comment: Why .htaccess? Why not add `+` in PHP when it is not there?

Comment: Well I'm game but how?  I've tried various ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the php function preg_match to handle your search.

Something like:

```
preg_match("~\b [$your_search_value] \b~",$were_to_search)
```

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283883/4601619

Read more about the preg_match function on:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php